# Repeated random numbers in R, how to stop?

Tags: r, random

I am generating a small collection of random uniform numbers in R (10,000 in this case), and I am finding repeats at an alarming rate (say once every few repetitions on the 10,000 number draw). Why is this happening, and how can I stop it (efficiently)?

Here is a min working example where I just go ahead and draw 1 million unif(0,1) values. This seems to generate many repeated values. I did have some problems with finding the repeats, so had to do some ugly stuff below, and there is a chance this might fail to find repeats sometimes due to rounding or something, but it seems to work on my machine.

```
rs_val <- .Random.seed 
tvals <- runif(10^6,0,1) 
tr1 <- as.numeric(names(which(table(tvals)>1)))[1] 
tr_idx <- which(abs(tvals-tr1)<0.000000001) 
tr_idx[1]
tr_idx[2]
format(tvals[tr_idx[1]],digits=22) 
format(tvals[tr_idx[2]],digits=22) 
tvals[tvals==as.numeric(format(tvals[tr_idx[1]],digits=22))]
```

Presumably, 1 million draws shouldn't be that much at all for a modern pseudo-random number generator, yes? I've seen a few posts here about similar issues with C++, but none on R. In the latter it had something to do with the random draws occurring faster than the random seed resetting or something like that.

Can somebody provide an efficient modification to the above code to prevent the repeated random number issue? Basically, I'm just simulating a Poisson process on a long timeline, and this is causing simultaneous events, which is problematic. I suppose, I could just go through the simulation and discard the repeated draws, but it would be nice to not have to do that.

Comment: Every number is equally likely under a unform draw.  You are imposing _an additional constraint of not desiring replicates_ which makes this a different problem:  you want to _sample_ 10^6 number (out a larger set) and not have replications.  See `help(sample)` for that.

Comment: Although I agree with @jdods that it does seem problematic for there to be multiple duplicates that are equivalent to a tolerance of 1e-22 in a set of only 1e6 draws from a uniform distribution. I just tested it on my system and got one pair of duplicates.

Comment: *"That's the problem with randomness: you can never be sure"*, https://www.americanscientist.org/article/the-quest-for-randomness and Dilbert's "Tour of Accounting".

Comment: @qdread My MWE only outputs a single duplicated pair, but the entire list can be accessed with "as.numeric(names(which(table(tvals)>1)))"

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Sure, but as an approximation to the uniform distribution, getting repeats after a few thousand draws is very sub-optimal and a poor approximation to a theoretical uniform random draw. And it doesn't work for simulating a Poisson process. I did find RNGkind(kind="Wichmann-Hill") solves the issue. Maybe your hint was meant to point me there.

Comment: Testing random number generators is a large field of study -- see e.g. [RDieHarder](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=RDieHarder) on CRAN and other tester kits.  I simply wanted to point out that _just by accessing an RNG_ I think you cannot get guarantees over the property of uniqueness you tested and (implicitly at least) claimed should hold.  Then are also quasi- or [low-discrepancy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) and those sometimes show the scatter plots you may have had in mind. Base RNGs just don't AFAIK. Anyway, _huge_ field of study.

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, please post it **as an answer** and not as an update to your question. You can accept your own answer if you think it's the best one -- nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Caleb Done. I feel like that is frowned upon at MathSE, which is where I mostly post, so I didn't think to consider that the cultural standard was different here (or that I maybe misinterpret the cultural standard at MathSE!).

Comment: You can also take a look at `bit64::runif64`. Seems like it could fit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @jdods. meta.math.se suggests that [it's fine to answer your own question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/is-answering-own-question-okay) even there, but I don't spend a lot of time there so perhaps there's more to it. In general, answering your own question is fine, and certainly better than leaving a question unanswered so that it continues to show up in the unanswered questions list.

Comment: There's nothing about Poisson processes that disallows simultaneous events.  In fact, simultaneous photon absorptions are how certain passive Q-switch materials work.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the standard poisson process has probability zero for simultaneous events. Sure that can be interpreted as different from it being impossible, but it was causing problems for my particular application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?Random`:

> Do not rely on randomness of low-order bits from RNGs. Most of the
> supplied uniform generators return 32-bit integer values that are
> converted to doubles, so they take at most 2^32 distinct values and
> long runs will return duplicated values (Wichmann-Hill is the
> exception, and all give at least 30 varying bits.)

This is easy to verify:

```
identical(min(diff(unique(sort(runif(1e6))))), 2^-32)
#> [1] TRUE
sum((runif(1e6) %% 2^-32))
#> [1] 0
```

So another option besides using Wichmann-Hill is to sample `1:(2^32 - 1)` without replacement and divide by `2^32`, although, this is not as performant as `runif` with Wichmann-Hill.

```
system.time(x <- sample(2^32 - 1, 1e6)/2^32)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.16    0.01    0.17
RNGkind(kind="Wichmann-Hill")
system.time(x <- runif(1e6))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.04    0.00    0.05
```

A second option is to call `runif` twice: once for 32-bit precision, and then a second call to fill in the gaps to make it double precision:

```
RNGkind(kind="default")

runif64 <- function(n) runif(n) + runif(n, -2^-33, 2^-32 - 2^-33)
x <- runif64(1e6)
range(x)
#> [1] 4.710828e-07 9.999975e-01
anyDuplicated(x)
#> [1] 0
```

`runif64` is about twice as slow as just calling `runif`.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  runif64(1e6),
  runif(1e6)
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>            expr     min       lq     mean median       uq      max neval
#>  runif64(1e+06) 61.1622 63.33880 65.91086 64.926 67.18855 109.3689   100
#>    runif(1e+06) 29.7481 30.34125 31.91007 30.997 33.71515  40.3735   100
```

The probability of seeing any duplicate values in `1e6` samples of `2^64` possible values is very small:

```
library(Rmpfr)

n <- mpfr(2^64, 128)
m <- mpfr(1e6, 128)
as.numeric(1 - exp(lgamma(n + 1) - m*log(n) - lgamma(n - m + 1)))
#> [1] 2.710503e-08
```

Comment: Thank you for this analysis and the various techniques!

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465536/r-problem-with-runif-generated-number-repeats-more-often-than-expected-after

Set the RNGkind to "Wichmann-Hill" whereas the default in R is "Mersenne-Twister". I'm sure there are pros and cons of each specific method, but I just need to ensure there are no repeats and that it is reasonably uniform.

```
RNGkind(kind="Wichmann-Hill")
```

Note that "Wichmann-Hill" kind is apparently "predictable" (as noted in the linked post). I don't think that is a problem for my particular application as I just need roughly random uniform draws with no repeats.

Comment: Why is this better than what D. Eddebuettel showed, i.e. you should just create a random **order** of the values 1:N  ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I didn't understand what he was suggesting. That I create a large list of "uniform draws"and then resample them?

Comment: @jods  `foo <- sample(1:1e20, 1:1e20, replace=FALSE);  bar <- foo[1:1e6]/1e20`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "Error in 1:1e+20 : result would be too long a vector"

Comment: The now-added answer by @jblood94 shows it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I see. 10^20 was too big for my computer. 2^51 and 10^15 were as large as I could go. I'm very glad to know this technique! I didn't know R could do that without actually creating the vector to sample from! I actually implemented the pnorm(rnorm()) technique. I'll test them all to see what is fastest.